# Filtering GeoJson data by property to get a subset of data

Tags: javascript, geojson

I am trying to get a subset of Geojson Data by property.

```
 {
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ -115.5578333,32.9646667 ]
    },
    "properties": {
    "Year1979_03":2.92606854,
    "Year1979_06":2.963032273,
    "Year1979_09":2.968127935
    }
  }]
```

If a user chooses year "Year1979_03 then then it should return

```
{
       "type": "FeatureCollection",
       "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
           "type": "Point",
           "coordinates":  [ -115.5578333,32.9646667 ]
        },
        "properties": {
        "Year1979_03":2.92606854,
        }
      }]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you have a user input and you have it in a variable:

```
let userInput = "Year1979_03"
```

and you have the returned data in its original form

```
let originalData = {
   "type": "FeatureCollection",
   "features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
       "type": "Point",
       "coordinates":  [ -115.5578333,32.9646667 ]
    },
    "properties": {
        "Year1979_03":2.92606854,
        "Year1979_06":2.963032273,
        "Year1979_09":2.968127935
    }
   }
  ]
 }
```

then you can use es6 spread operator to create the object you wanted to create:

```
let reformedData = {
    ...originalData, 
    "features": [
    {
     ...originalData.features[0], 
     "properties": 
    {
     [userInput]: originalData.features[0].properties[userInput] 
    } 
   }] 
  }
```

Above, I use the spread operator to retrieve all the keys and values I want to keep from the originalData object, but specify the ones I want to change/replace. This would bring you the object you wanted.